Where can I buy the book Hanosein Imrei Shefer?
Does anyone know where I could buy the book Hanosein Imrei Shefer (הנותן אמרי שפר) by Rabbi Yeshaya Naftoli Herz Spira of Dinov זצ״ל? I have looked in a number of different places and have been unable thus far to find a copy.

Looks like it's out of print for many years (there was one printed in NYC in 1960). Aside from checking with the typical sellers of used seforim, would an online version be sufficient for your interest?

בדיעבד ........

https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/61011/p/1/t/1734364963789/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c (free access to the early pages of the sefer / if you are affiliated with a school or library that has access then free to view the entire sefer)

@Y DJ - are you sure you navigated to the correct URL? see answer below.

@EraserX sorry, I do not have a login. So it bounces my phone to general search and then it picks the other sefer.

If you are open to borrowing it: https://search.worldcat.org/title/122844341

since I can't paste an image into a comment, will do this as an answer, albeit a בדיעבד one
This is the first page I get when I navigate to the link I posted in the comment above - https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/61011/p/1/t/1734364963789/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c


Thanks. This link works.
